# How to chain a Promise.all with other Promises?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I want to execute my code in the following order:

1. Promise 1
2. Wait for 1 to be done, then do Promise 2+3 at the same time
3. Final function waits for Promise 2+3 to be done

I'm having some trouble figuring it out, my code so far is below.

```
function getPromise1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do something async
    resolve('myResult');
  });
}

function getPromise2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do something async
    resolve('myResult');
  });
}

function getPromise3() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do something async
    resolve('myResult');
  });
}

getPromise1()
.then(
  Promise.all([getPromise2(), getPromise3()])
  .then() // ???
)
.then(() => console.log('Finished!'));
```

Comment: As adeneo explained, whatever you return from a then handler is passed on to the next handler

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just return `Promise.all(...`

```
getPromise1().then(() => {
  return Promise.all([getPromise2(), getPromise3()]);
}).then((args) => console.log(args)); // result from 2 and 3
```

Comment: or use `spread` if you want to chain another promises in a neat way ;)

Comment: @Yerken `spread` is great, but isn't that a `Bluebird` extension, and not ES6?

Comment: yup sorry, you are right. But hopefully one day it will become part of the standard :)

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't realize you had to "return Promise.all(...)" - I was doing it without the return and noticed it wasnt executing in order...

Answer (score 17):

I know it's an old thread, but isn't

```
() => {return Promise.all([getPromise2(), getPromise3()]);}
```

a little superfluous? The idea of fat arrow is that you can write it as:

```
() => Promise.all([getPromise2(), getPromise3()])
```

which makes the resulting code somewhat clearer:

```
getPromise1().then(() => Promise.all([getPromise2(), getPromise3()]))
.then((args) => console.log(args)); // result from 2 and 3
```

Anyway, thanks for the answer, I was stuck with this :)