# Mongodb Node Driver - does it really matter when I call db.close() or am I getting lucky?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've found that db.close() does not seem to close until all reads or writes have finished regardless of when it is called. This is actually what I would want, but I want to make sure this is the intended behavior and not just me getting lucky. I have some code like this:

```
...
{
  collection.insertMany(...).then(()=> { console.log("inserted") })
  collection.deleteMany(...).then(()=> { console.log("deleted") })
}).then(() =>
{
  console.log("will close");
  client.close();
}).catch((reason) => { console.log(reason) });
```

I get output like:

```
will close
deleted
inserted
```

but no errors and upon further testing, the proper records were in fact inserted and deleted. In the documentation we see that they call db.close() in whatever the final callback is, but I did not do it then. Is this reliable? I'm not sure how to restructure my code to make it more clear that the close is issued after both the insertMany and deleteMany - perhaps I should be using promise.all.

**EDIT**
So both of the answers below make sense to me as to how they would guarantee the connection closing at the appropriate time, with Neil Lunn's suggestion to use bulkWrite seeming ideal for performance reasons. I'll likely go the bulkWrite route in my application for the time being for the sake of good practice, but I still have some confusion regarding my original question...

To me it seems the code above issues insertMany and deleteMany before client.close() regardless, so I would think mongodb is aware that there are pending operations, so will close appropriately. Can someone give me an example scenario as to how client.close() can be called prematurely? If the assumption is that an error in either of the operations can result in client.close() being called early, then I propose adding

```
{
  collection.insertMany(...).then(()=> { console.log("inserted") })
  collection.deleteMany(...).then(()=> { console.log("deleted") })
}).then(() =>
{
  console.log("will close");
}).catch((reason) => { console.log(reason) })
  .then(() => { client.close() })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to chain a Promise.all with other Promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759061/how-to-chain-a-promise-all-with-other-promises)

Comment: you're getting lucky.

Comment: I understand that promise.all can be used as has been demonstrated by sven - makes sense, but my question is intended to be more mongodb focused. Hopefully my recent edit explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all honesty, you're not only "getting lucky" with the actions happening to resolve before you call `client.close()` but also there could be a "potential" problem with the two statements running in parallel.

Ideally you would instead use [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) and make a "single" request with both actions contained in it. The "single request" also has a "single response", therefore no issue with awaiting resolution of multiple promises:

```
collection.bulkWrite(
  [
    ...listOfInsertDocuments.map(document => ({ "insertOne": { document } })),
    { "deleteMany": { "filter": filterCondition } }
  ]
)
.then(() => console.log("will close"))
.catch(e => console.error(e))
.then(() => client.close());
```

The default action of [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) is that operations are "ordered" and execute serially in the same order in which they were presented in the array of "actions" presented. The [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) used here to create the `insertOne` actions is in fact exactly what the [`insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#insertMany) method actually does in the underlying driver implementation.

In fact ALL such driver methods actually call the underlying "Bulk API" methods as the modern way of doing things. The [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) explicitly abstracts from the actual "Bulk API" in order to gracefully downgrade the requests to the "legacy" API when connecting to a MongoDB instance earlier than MongoDB 2.6.

The other way to do this is "parallel" execution by explicitly setting `"ordered": false`:

```
collection.bulkWrite(
  [
  ...listOfInsertDocuments.map(document => ({ "insertOne": { document } })),
  { "deleteMany": { "filter": filterCondition } }
  ],
  { "ordered": false }
)
.then(() => console.log("will close"))
.catch(e => console.error(e))
.then(() => client.close());
```

That deliberately means that none of the actions are dependent on the others completing "first". So if indeed you are "inserting" something which you are also "deleting", then there is no guarantee which will happen in any particular order.

Aside from "parallelism", the general purpose of `"ordered": false` is to allow continuation "on error". In such a case, all "batched" actions are actually attempted and in the exception response you get detail telling you at which "index positions" in the array of provided actions there was any failure.

The behavior is then "sort of" done in "mimicry" by the following [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) invocation:

```
Promise.all([
  collection.insertMany(..., { "ordered": false }).then(()=> { console.log("inserted") }),
  collection.deleteMany(...).then(()=> { console.log("deleted") })
]).then(() => console.log("will close"))
.catch(e => console.error(e))
.then(() => client.close());
```

That of course executes in "parallel" but fires "multiple requests" which creates a greater overhead with back and forth communication to the server. The purpose of the earlier examples is to avoid that and therefore a better option.

And for "completeness" you can always of course "chain" the promises:

```
  collection.insertMany(...)
    .then(() => console.log("inserted")),
    .then(() => collection.deleteMany(...)
    .then(()=> console.log("deleted"))
    .then(() => console.log("will close"))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
    .then(() => client.close());
```

In that way "everything" is serial in execution, but of course they all fire separate requests.

So whilst there are ways to handle "awaiting" the Promise resolution, it's usually better to make "one call" and just await that "Bulk" response instead.

Comment: could the .then before the .catch be removed and instead have the console.log("will close") moved to the final .then with the same effect?

Comment: @Arman The point of the `then()` shown "after" the `catch()` is to demonstrate that the code in there "runs" regardless of any error. It's basically the common reproduction of `finally` in a standard `try...catch..finally` but in a way which is supported in older promise implementations ( and possibly existing since I did not check Node 10 ). It's "demonstration". Realistically both statements belong at the end of the "full" promise chain, whatever that may be. Also in something like a "web server" you don't call `close()` ever. It's only usage is with "one shot" scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the queries to complete. You can do so by returning `Promise.all([query1, query2])`, which will resolve when both promises returned by the queries are fulfilled. Additionally, use the Promise's [`.finally()`-method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) to ensure `client.close()` is called, even if there is an error. With your current code, if an error occurs the `client.close()` will not be called.

```
...
{
  return Promise.all([
    collection.insertMany(...).then(()=> { console.log("inserted") }),
    collection.deleteMany(...).then(()=> { console.log("deleted") })
  ]);
}).then(() => {
  console.log("will close");
}).catch((reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
}).finally(() => {
  client.close();
});
```

Comment: Granted you can await the Promise(s) resolution with `Promise.all()`, however MongoDB actually has a more specific method for this purpose which avoids the overhead of "multiple requests" and waiting for them to resolve. Also not sure if `Promise.finally()` is fully ratified in NodeJS yet, and usually needs a plugin or "bluebird promises" with most versions in use at least. So probably better with a plain `then()`, which works just the same anyway when placed after `catch()`. ( which itself is just "sugar" really).  But kudos anyway.